# How to pop UINavigationController to the caller

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a UIViewController that is not on the navigation stack. It initialises another UIViewController which is on the top of the stack. The new root controller pushes more controllers on the stack and so on.

Now, I will need to pop all controllers down back to the controller which started the process. However, popToRootViewControllerAnimated doesn't work.

ie: A -> B -> C -> D where B, C and D are on the navigation stack and I need to go back to controller A from D. How to do it?

```
-(void) loadScreenWithNavigation:(UIViewController *)controller
{    
    _navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:(_loadedController = controller)];
    _navController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;
    _navController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;

    [self.view addSubview:[_navController view]];
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:[_navController view]];
}
```

That's how I started the navigation stack in my "home" controller. I need to come back to the home controller.

Comment: can you tell how the UIViewController, which is not on navigation stack, initializes another viewcontroller???

Comment: [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES] isn't working for me since it only goes back to controller B. I need A, not B. How would people solve this kind of problems?

Comment: Any particular reason you're not using `pushViewController`?

Comment: Do you mean initialise the UINavigationController then push controller B rather than using initWithRootController?

Answer (score 5):

Use standard `UINavigationController`'s method:

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Then, you can `removeFromSuperview` your custom initialized view.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you want to remove this [_navController view] right?
which you can do as follows :

```
 if([_navController.view superview])
        [_navController.view removeFromSuperview];
```

**EDIT:**

In a simplified way, any UIViewController will disappear in the same fashion it appeared. If any view was added as

1.) addSubView method :

> [self.view addSubView: myView];

it would be removed by

> [myView removeFromSuperView];

2.) stack it to navigationController

> [self.navigationController pushViewController:objctOfYourViewController animated:YES];

this view will pop out of stack as

> [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

3.) present modal view

> [self presentModalViewController:objctOfYourViewController animated:NO];

which will be removed as

> [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

Now, just in the way you added your views, you should make them remove.

Comment: Well, this method must be in controller B. Then after calling this method to populate controller B visibly (which works), how do we deallocate controller B (which is itself)? Obviously, controller B can't deallocate itself.

Answer (score 1):

In AppDelegate,

```
UINavigationController *navController;
```

in AppDelegate.m file,

```
self.navController=[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:yourViewController];

[self.window addSubview:self.navController.view];
```

when you push yourViewcontrollerA to viewcontrollerB ,

```
[self.navigationController viewcontrollerB animated:YES];
```

same for viewControllerB to C and C to D ..

now if You want to go back D to C then,

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: You can't add itself as the root controller, this would crash.